# How to get value from the object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I wrote an object, it has 4 keys and values. How can I get the keys and values separately using a `for` loop?

I tried the below code, but no luck.

```
var timeObject = {
    getNewYorkLocalTime: 'getTime.php?lat=40.7143528&lan=-74.0059731',
    getLondonLocalTime: 'getTime.php?lat=51.5001524&lan=-0.1262362',
    getChennaiLocalTime: 'getTime.php?lat=13.060422&lan=80.249583',
    getBangaloreLocalTime: 'getTime.php?lat=12.9715987&lan=77.5945627'
}

for (var x in timeObject) {
    alert(timeObject[x].value);
}
```

Can anyone help me? I'm using jQuery in this page, so a jQuery solution is ok too.

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery, you can loop through with [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

```
$.each(timeObject, function(key, value) {

});
```

However, your loop isn't far off:

```
for (var x in timeObject) {
    alert('key: ' + x + ' value=' + timeObject[x]);
}
```

In this `for..in` loop, `x` is the key name.  You can then access it on the object `timeObject` using the standard member operator. See [the MDC documentation for `for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Answer (score 1):

I think you sholu do something like this:

```
var timeObject = {
    getNewYorkLocalTime: 'getTime.php?lat=40.7143528&lan=-74.0059731',
    getLondonLocalTime: 'getTime.php?lat=51.5001524&lan=-0.1262362',
    getChennaiLocalTime: 'getTime.php?lat=13.060422&lan=80.249583',
    getBangaloreLocalTime: 'getTime.php?lat=12.9715987&lan=77.5945627'
}

for (var x in timeObject) {
    //use this check to avoid messing up with prototype properties
    if (timeObject.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
        alert(timeObject[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: as far as I know, prototype properties won't be applicable here since you're working with an object and not a native array.

Comment: @JohnP Unless you've defined `Object.prototype.contains` or somesuch.

Comment: @JohnP I think i'ts always better if you filter out any prototype chains if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it. You don't need the extra `value` at the end.

Working code

```
var timeObject = {
    getNewYorkLocalTime: 'getTime.php?lat=40.7143528&lan=-74.0059731',
    getLondonLocalTime: 'getTime.php?lat=51.5001524&lan=-0.1262362',
    getChennaiLocalTime: 'getTime.php?lat=13.060422&lan=80.249583',
    getBangaloreLocalTime: 'getTime.php?lat=12.9715987&lan=77.5945627'
}

for (var x in timeObject) {
    console.log(timeObject[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's still actual - [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) may help you. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SK4Eu/

```
var timeObject = {
    getNewYorkLocalTime: 'getTime.php?lat=40.7143528&lan=-74.0059731',
    getLondonLocalTime: 'getTime.php?lat=51.5001524&lan=-0.1262362',
    getChennaiLocalTime: 'getTime.php?lat=13.060422&lan=80.249583',
    getBangaloreLocalTime: 'getTime.php?lat=12.9715987&lan=77.5945627'
}

var keys = Object.keys(timeObject),
    keysLength = keys.length;

for (var i = 0; i < keysLength; i++) {
    alert(timeObject[keys[i]]);
}
```